# Hamel basis for subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hamel-basis

Quick question about basis. Assume you have a separable, reflexive Banach space $X$ with a Schauder basis $\{e_{i}\}$. If you form subspaces $X_{n}$ such that $X_{n} = \text{span}\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{n}\}$. Then can you consider each $X_{n}$ as Banach space with Hamel basis $\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{n}\}$ since any $x \in X_{n}$ can be written as a finite linear combination of linearly independent basis vectors $\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{n}\}$?

Comment: When you use the notation $\mathrm{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, for a finite $n$, by definition you are forming the vector space from finite linear combinations of the $v_i$'s, so you immediately retrieve a Hamel basis if the $v_i$'s are linearly independent.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Okay thanks. Do you mind if I email you a question about something else? I saw your topics of interest and think that maybe you might have insight into something else.

Comment: I do not mind, I would be happy to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

> When you use the notation $\mathrm{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, for a finite $n$, by definition you are forming the vector space from finite linear combinations of the $v_i$'s, so you immediately retrieve a Hamel basis if the $v_i$'s are linearly independent. --  [Christopher A. Wong](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/22059/christopher-a-wong)